# PHPUnit testing for functions not within any class

Tags: php, phpunit

I am newbie to PHPUnit testing. I just downloaded PHPUnit. The examples that I saw were all for .php files, with functions within class. The files that i have for testing just contains on load functions or functions which are called asynchronously with the help of AJAX **but are not within any classes**. Is there a way to test these or I need to refactor my entire code.

simpleTest.php

```
<?php
require 'simpleTestClass.php';

class simpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

public function testAdd(){

        $result = $this->add(1,2);
        $expected = 3;
        $this->assertTrue($result == $expected);
    }

}
```

simpleTestClass.php

```
<?php

     function add($a, $b){
        return $a + $b;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Does it respond to GET or POST request?

Comment: This is an example of how my .php looks like:
'<?php

     function add()
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
 
?>'

Comment: Testing a function : 1) the function is available everywhere. So, have a phpunit test class called something like 'TestMyInterestingFunction. Within that each method is just the same as testing a class 'method'. i.e. given function: 'isBirthdayToday' then you have test methods called, say: 'testBirthdayIsToday();' and 'testBirthdayIstomorrow()' etc.?

Comment: @RyanVincent I am not able to call the add method in my .php file. Please have a look at below code: –

simpleTest.php

`<?php
require 'simpleTestClass.php';
 
class simpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
 
    public function testAdd(){

        $result = $this->add(1,2);
        $expected = 3;
        $this->assertTrue($result == $expected);
    }
 
}`

simpleTestClass.php:

`<?php

  function add($a, $b){
     return $a + $b;
 }
?>`

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent. I have added the code.

Comment: maybe interesting? [phpunit test for your function?](http://pastebin.com/QbxK8ff5)

Comment: `$this->add(1,2);` indicates you're calling a method on the instantiated `simpleTest` object, not a function in the global namespace. I anticipate you mean `$result = add(1,2);`.

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish, that worked. But for better practice, i went on to change my .php files so they follow OOP syntax.